# How to prepare a live video stream to be fed to an HTML5 Video MediaSource?

Tags: html5-video, gstreamer, h.264

I have a transfer of a live video stream from a server to the javascript function of a client browser:

```
server: gstreamer x264enc-hardware ! whatever-I-want ! appsink

=== transfer of data stream with a proprietary protocol ===>

HTML5 browser client: javascript function receives data sent by the appsink
```

In other words, I'm trying to display a h264 live stream created on a server with a proprietary transfer protocol, the data re-appearing in a javascript function inside an HTML5 client browser.

I was thinking of using **MediaSource MSE** in the browser to decode h264 and display the image.

Note that the video stream settings (video only, resolution, bandwidth) are fixed and known on both sides. So, everything can be hard-coded and the purpose is not to implement a generic solution.

What could I use on the server side (replacement of the "whatever-I-want" gstreamer plugin) so that the work in the HTML5 browser is not too complicated?

One solution would be to do nothing on the server side and use the [broadway.js](https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway) library to decode NALU h264 in javascript but it obviously doesn't leverage video MediaSource and the decoding capability of the browser.

Could I use [Gstreamer avmux_dash](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/libav/avmux_dash.html?gi-language=c) and hope that MediaSource can input the transmitted data?

Alternatively, how could I create "MP4 fragments" and could MediaSource read them "easily"?

Answer (score 1):

One approach, that has been used by some major players in the past to translate from one streaming protocol to another, is to receive in your proprietary transfer protocol and then re-package into HLS or DASH on a local server on the device.

You can then stream from that local host to a regular HLS or DASh player on the device.

It sounds inefficient (it is inefficient) but it works, even on mobile devices which their lower processing and power capabilities.

Comment: It's a good answer - and I thought about it! ;-). But still not exactly what I want. It's like having an apple in your garden, calling the distribution company to grab it and go at the store to buy it...